# Can not import CouchBase Lite as a module

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I need to import `Couchbase Lite` in one of my proyects. I dont want to use `Gradle` . So basically what I am doing is :

1. I have donwloaded the proyect from [github](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java-core)
2. I have imported it like a new module (File->New->Impor module->path)

After compilate the proyect I am facing an error,

> Cannot resolve symbol AndroidContext

so I need the class

> AndroidContext

That class is [here](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java-core) so I am trying to import it like the previuse one, like a module, but I am facing this error.

[image]

What I am doing wrong? What I should do for import CouchBase lite to android not using

> compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.4.0'

Comment: I think you should be using couchbase-lite-android for an Android project (which has java-core as its dependency)

Comment: and How I can do it ?

Comment: I suppose start by downloading the [Android project](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android) instead of just java-core?

Comment: Tkans, I tried it but I got the same error taht you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Hi @JoCuTo,
Do you want to integrate CBL source into your Android project? If so, you could refer the following documentation. https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/wiki/Add-Couchbase-Lite-to-your-project-as-a-submodule .

Comment: @hideki Yes I want to integrate CBL in my code in order to  set usePOST variable in ChangeTracker to false. I am still stuck with the solution that you propose, it does not work in my case. I have followed all the steps

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: :commons-io-2.0.1:
Error:Failed to resolve: :couchbase-lite-android-1.4.0:    I get his error in allthe jar

Comment: @JoCuTo `commons-io-2.0.1` is only used for unit test. You could ignore it if you want.
I think your environment might not configure the maven repo with jcenter? https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/commons-io%3Acommons-io/2.0.1

Comment: thanks @hideki I really apreciate your support but I can not import the librery , I dont know what to do. ¿could you please provide us a complete tutorial about how to import  ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929314/empty-folder-importing-external-librery

Comment: @JoCuTo Please try submodule solution with following the instruction in the link.
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/wiki/Add-Couchbase-Lite-to-your-project-as-a-submodule

Comment: Now I can import it but If I Build and .apk I get:
Error:Execution failed for task ':libraries:couchbase-lite-java-forestdb:buildNative'.
> Process 'command 'C:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2   I have been reading this issue but aparently the problem is not solved
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/820

Comment: If I try again git submodule update --init --recursive I get Failed to clone 'vendor/couchbase-lite-libcrypto' a second time, aborting     
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'libraries/couchbase-lite-android/libraries/couchbase-lite-java-native/vendor/sqlcipher'
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'libraries/couchbase-lite-android/libraries/couchbase-lite-java-native'
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'libraries/couchbase-lite-android'

Comment: Since I have red  that libreries are required for tests only I have just removed it from my proyect and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of other dependencies that you might need:

```
    implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.4.4'
    // To access the database through HTTP (often used for hybrid development and peer-to-peer sync).
    implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-java-listener:1.4.4'
    // To use ForestDB as the storage type.
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-forestdb:1.4.4'
    // To enable encryption on SQLite databases.
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-sqlcipher:1.4.4'
    // JavaScript view (map/reduce) engine for the REST API.    
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-java-javascript:1.4.4'
```

Full documentation of gradle includes is [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/1.4/java.html).